# JWT token not setting inside the cookies after deploying but works in localhost

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt, mern, vercel

So My Problem is that recently I deployed my MERN stack site to Vercel ( my api and my frontend )
there's a login and register page.
[Look at the top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j2bJ.png)

After Login
[See Welcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47kz6.png)

Now the issue is that When I refreshes the Page , again the login and register state comes instead of
Welcome User.

This is completely working on my Localhost:3000 as if i reload , the JWT token are stored in my cookies(chrome / inspectElement / network / cookies ) but as soon as i deployed , this issue started after refreshing the page.

**Imports :**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const cors = require('cors')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const UserModel = require('./models/User')
const CookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const multer = require('multer') 
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const PostModel = require("./models/Post.js")

// app.use(cors({credentials : true , origin : 'https://blogifyv1.vercel.app'}))
app.use(cors({credentials : true , origin : true}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(CookieParser())
app.use('/uploads',express.static(__dirname + '/uploads')) // for the image to be display on the website from uploads folder.

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended : false
}))
```

**Login Route** :

1. Before adding the domain in res.cookie

   ```
   app.post('/login',async(req,res)=>{
       const {username , password} = req.body;
       try {
           const userDoc = await UserModel.findOne({username : username})
           const passwordMatched = await bcrypt.compareSync(password , userDoc.password)
           console.log("isValid",passwordMatched)

           // now token...
           if(passwordMatched){
               // loggedIn
               jwt.sign({username , id:userDoc._id}, secretSalt,{},(err,token)=>{
                   if(err){
                       throw err;
                   }
                   else{
                       res.cookie('token',token).json({
                           id : userDoc._id,
                           username
                       })
                   }
               })
           }
           else{
               res.status(400).json("Wrong Credentials")
           }
           // res.json(userDoc)
       } catch (err) {
           console.log(err)
           res.status(400).json(err)
       }
   })
   ```

   2. After adding the domain in cookie

```
 
    app.post('/login',async(req,res)=>{
        const {username , password} = req.body;
        try {
            const userDoc = await UserModel.findOne({username : username})
            const passwordMatched = await bcrypt.compareSync(password , userDoc.password)
            console.log("isValid",passwordMatched)
    
            // now token...
            if(passwordMatched){
                // loggedIn
                jwt.sign({username , id:userDoc._id}, secretSalt,{},(err,token)=>{
                    if(err){
                        throw err;
                    }
                    else{
                        res.cookie('token',token,{ domain: '.vercel.app', secure: true }).json({
                            id : userDoc._id,
                            username
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
            else{
                res.status(400).json("Wrong Credentials")
            }
            // res.json(userDoc)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(400).json(err)
        }
    })
```

**Create Post Route**

```
// logout endpoint

app.post('/logout',async(req,res)=>{
    res.cookie('token' , "").json("ok")
})


app.post('/post',uploadMiddleware.single('file'),async(req,res)=>{//note,this 'file' is the data.set('file',file) as we putted into CreatePost.js
    res.json({files : req.file})
    console.log("file", req.file)
    console.log("filename", req.file?.filename)
    const {token} = req.cookies

    jwt.verify(token,secretSalt,{},async (err,info)=>{
        if(err) throw err;

        const  {title , summary,content} = req.body;
        const postDoc = await PostModel.create({
            title,
            summary,
            content,
            cover : req.file.filename,
            author : info.id,
        })
        res.json(postDoc)
    })
})
```

**React.js Components :**

1. Login.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import Form from '../components/Form'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { UserContext } from '../contextapi/UserContext';

const Login = () => {
  const [username , setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password , setPassword] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const {setUserInfo} = useContext(UserContext);

  const login=async(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://mern-blog-api-rho.vercel.app/login',{
            method: "POST",
            body : JSON.stringify({username , password}),
            headers: {'Content-type' : 'application/json'},
            credentials: "include",  // enabling to add the cookies.. from the server 
        })
        console.log(response)
        if(response.status === 200){
          response.json().then((userInfo)=>{
            setUserInfo(userInfo)
            navigate('/')
          })
        }
        else{
            alert('Registration Failed , try again later')
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

}
```

**Vercel.json :**

```
{
    "version":2,
    "builds":[
        {"src":"./index.js","use":"@vercel/node"}
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
          "src": "/(.*)",
          "dest": "/",
          "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
          "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me to get out of this problem

Comment: Can you check your console in the frontend and add the log output? You can also check the stored cookies in developer console in your frontend.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus when i did document.cookie inside the console , its showing an empty string " "

Comment: Even after logging in to your deployed application? Can you check if the "Set-Cookie" header is present on your response headers of the `/login` call?

Comment: @FabianStrathaus yeah i checked the response headers and after that i entered my username and password and hit login and then went to the : network < / loginRoute < headers . Yes , cookie is present eg: set-cookie: token="values....."

Comment: @FabianStrathaus

Comment: I am not sure where you are setting the login state after all in your frontend. Only in the login function? Or do you also have another function where `setUserInfo(userInfo)` is called?

Comment: I have used React ContextAPI which do the following :    const [userInfo , setUserInfo] = useState({})  and simply returns the { children }  nothing else.

Comment: this is my github for the code: https://github.com/yash-devop/MERN-Blog

Comment: @FabianStrathaus